# Nested Conditional statements in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot my data points (**see below**) ***as characters*** in an R scatterplot. Data points based on the value of their grouping variable **"z"** (**1, 2, 3**) are to appear in **3 distinct colors**.

**1-** I was wondering how I can **modify my current R code (see below)** to achieve these 3 distinct colors for the 3 groups' data points?

**2-** Is there a way I can italicize and bold data points for which **z** is **1** and **2**, respectively?

```
x <- c(2,1,5,4,5,8,6,6,4,1,2,2,2,5,9,5,4,3,2,3,1,3,1,7,3,2,2,9,7,7,9,8,8,6,4,6,7,2,1,4,3,9)
y <- c(1,1,2,8,7,4,6,7,5,5,2,9,3,9,1,5,7,1,8,6,8,4,9,2,7,5,7,6,3,8,3,3,7,8,3,4,4,4,3,6,5,4)
z <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,2)

plot(0:10,0:10,type="n",axes=F)
box()
text(x,y,col=ifelse(x[which(z==1)],"Red",ifelse(x[which(z==2)],"blue","green")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When appropriate, many arguments in `plot`, `lines`, `text`, etc can take vector arguments. Try:

```
plot(0:10, 0:10, type = "n", axes = F)
text(x, y, col = c("red", "blue", "green")[z], font = c(3,2,1)[z])
```

[image: plot]

I might need to explain what `font` does. Check `?par`:

```
‘font’ An integer which specifies which font to use for text.  If
       possible, device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to
       plain text (the default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4
       to bold italic.  Also, font 5 is expected to be the symbol
       font, in Adobe symbol encoding.  On some devices font
       families can be selected by ‘family’ to choose different sets
       of 5 fonts.
```

Answer (score 1):

with ggplot:

```
x <- as.factor(x)
y <- as.factor(y)
z <- as.factor(z)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_text(aes(x, y, label=seq_along(x), col=z, 
           fontface = ifelse(z==3, 'plain', 'bold.italic'))) + 
           scale_color_manual(values=c('red','blue','green')) + theme_bw()
```

[image]